# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in

Tags: php

What is causing this error?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in C:\wamp\www\game\rankings.php on line 19

Here is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
  echo "You must be logged in to view this page";
}else{ 
  ?>
  <center><h2>Battle Players</h2></center>
  <br />
  <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td width="50px"><b>Rank</b></td>
      <td width="150px"><b>Username</b></td>
      <td width="200px"><b>Gold</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $get_users = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`overall` FROM `ranking` WHERE `overall`>'0' ORDER BY `overall` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_users)) { var_dump($row)
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $row['overall']. "</td>";
    $get_user = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `user` WHERE `id`='".$row['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $rank_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user);
    echo "<td><a href=\"stats.php?id=" .$row['id']."\">" . $rank_name['username'] . "</a></td>";
    $get_gold = mysql_query("SELECT `gold` FROM `stats` WHERE `id`='".$row['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $rank_gold = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_gold);
    echo "<td>" . number_format($rank_gold['gold']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
  </table>
  <?php
}
include("footer.php");
?>
```

also at  http://pastebin.com/3nw310en

Comment: How is that not obvious? You're missing semicolon on previous line.

Comment: Please post your code here to help future users that have the same problem.

Comment: This usually means that you forgot a semicolon on the line before the error occurred.

Comment: Oh i have a differant problem then ill have to ask a new question :(

Comment: @Arm103 Syntax error questions will always be closed because they've all been asked before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Missing `;` after `var_dump($row)`