# Parse error:syntax error,unexpected 'echo'(T_ECHO)

Tags: php

I want to create an event calendar but I got this message below after I execute the code below.

> Parse error:syntax error,unexpected 'echo'(T_ECHO)

the error is on this line

```
return '<li id="li-'.$this->currentDate;?> <a href="index.php?tarikh=<?php echo $readrow['fld_tarikh']; ?>"></a><?php '"class=btn btn-info btn-lg data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal""'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
            ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContent.'</li>'
```

I'm trying to find the solution, but failed. so, i really hope that someone can help me. thank you...

Comment: Are you trying to open Popup in the Link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T\_ECHO in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689501/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-echo-in)

Comment: @KetanSolanki yup

Comment: Check your syntax properly the error related with your syntax you do not use php tags in html properly.

Comment: @yaya I think you are assigning some class named as `btn btn-info btn-lg` without any element I think that should be added inside `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
return '<li id="li-'.$this->currentDate;?> <a href="index.php?tarikh=<?php echo $readrow['fld_tarikh']; ?>"></a><?php echo "class=btn btn-info btn-lg data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'".($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContent.'</li>'
```

I think the problem is here,

```
<?php '"class=btn btn-info btn-lg data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal""'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' '))
```

`HTML` part is not getting echoed correctly.

Comment: I have tried ur coding. there is no error message but the button and date in the calendar does not appear.

Comment: i think after .$this->currentDate does not need ;?>  because if we put this ;?> the process will stop. so thats why the button does not appear..am i right? but, when i delete this ;?> part i got Parse error:syntax error,unexpected 'href'(T_STRING)

Comment: with the `?>` part you're closing your PHP you can try it any way I was jus going with the code you've supplied if there's more code which help to understand then please pot it and if my answer solved your problem then please mark it as the best answer and up vote it.

Comment: So in your calender.php have only this line ? if so remove the `?>` and concat the `<a ..` part with it.

Comment: ouh..no.that is not what i mean..sorry my mistake

Comment: ouh..no.that is not what i mean..sorry my mistake